# would you please provide a way to solve this question?

Tags: python

Write a python program that writes data to a file. The data consists of a series of
records, each with two fields – a name, followed by a grade (assuming that the grade
is non-negative, and no input validation is needed). Your program should:

1. Prompt the user to enter the number of records that he/she needs to enter.
2. Write the data to the file, with each entered value on a separate line.

Below is an example of what the expected output of your program should be (Do not use the
same inputs):

```
Enter the number of records that you need to enter: 3
Enter the name: Ahmad
Enter the grade: 93
Enter the name: Abir
Enter the grade: 95
Enter the name: Moatasem
Enter the grade: 78
```

b. Write a program that displays the name and score of the record with the highest
score, as well as the number of records in the above file.

The expected output, based on the above records should be as follows:

```
High Score: 95
Held By: Abir
Number of Scores: 3
```

This is my attempt:

```
def main() :
    stdfile = open('data.txt',"w")
    
    sname = input("Please input your fullname:")
    sgrade = input("Please input your grade:")
    
    stdfile.write(sname)
    stdfile.write(sgrade)
    stdfile.close()
    main()
```

if it's wrong or incomplete, please notify me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this.. def main() :
    stdfile = open('data.txt',"w")
    
    sname = input("Please input your fullname:")
    sgrade = input("Please input your grade:")
    
    stdfile.write(sname)
    stdfile.write(sgrade)
    stdfile.close()
    main()

Comment: Please put your attempt in your question body, not comment

Comment: Please change the post title to be more descriptive. People should be able to tell from the title whether or not that have the skills required to answer the question.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. This sounds like a homework question posted verbatim. This is not a site where people do your homework for you. There are two parts to the problem here, reading in the data, and writing the data. Which one are you having trouble with? Please post the actual behavior (e.g. traceback, or the expected vs actual file content.)

Comment: thank you for helping ....but you didnt have to be so rude ...i tried my best to solve and understand this problem and i had to ask about the correct way to solve in order to learn from your experience .

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
#prompt user to input the number of records to be entered
num_records = int(input('Enter number of records you need to enter: '))

#write data to file for each entry, change path to where you file is
file = open('file.txt', 'w+')

for i in range(num_records):

    #prompt user for input
    name = input('Enter name: ')
    grade = int(input('Enter grade: '))

    #write data to file
    file.write(name + ': ' + str(grade) + '\n')
    file.close
```

Comment: hi  i tried it and im seriously thankful for your help ...but would you just clarify the point of the file ...its the only bug im having ...

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. 
can you share your error message

Comment: it says file not found........should i name it after a file that i have on my pc?

Comment: Exactly!, I have made edited the answer too. That should work fine